# Colorbox call with dynamically created selectors

Tags: php, jquery-selectors, colorbox

I am getting error when generating javascript dynamically like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#$this->AddURLSegment").colorbox();
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="<?php echo $AddURLSegment;?>?width=500&height=500&iframe=false" id="<?php rcho $AddURLSegment;?>">Add</a>
```

Error:
First click on Add:

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

Second time:

```
ab.html(a.close).show is not a function
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
```

and 2 overlays open, one good and one broken.

! When i hardcode the selectors (ID name)  like so...., it works.

```
$("#add").colorbox();
```

What is gong on here!?

## EDIT:

Im doing this in silverstripe cms

The javascript (noconflict) is generated in Controller::init()

```
 Requirements::customScript('

            $j(document).ready(function(){
                $j("#'.$this->AddURLSegment.'").colorbox();
            });
');
```

The Html stuff is in View.

*SilverStripe is based on MVC paradigm.

Comment: Are you infusing php with javascript?  Post more of the surrounding code for the `$("#$this` segment.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to access $this->AddURLSegment from within Controller::init(). The AddURLSegment method is not available within the controller class. You need to call that in a subclass of controller. Most SilverStripe pages look like this:

Page extends SiteTree {
}

Page_Controller extends ContentController {
   public init() {
      Requirements::customScript(...);
   }
}

So, add the customScript into the controller of the page type you are using. That should make it work.

Comment: Yes this is all done inside SomePageType::init(), and i get the JS generated as it should be when i view html source.